# Insert before parent or itself (depending on if parent exist) JQuery

Tags: jquery, insert, parent

maybe you could help me, I have this code (If the parent exist insert before the parent, if not insert before itself)

```
if ($editingElem.parent(".form-submit").length) {
       $editingElem.parent().before(response.d.htmlUpdate);
}
else {
       $editingElem.before(response.d.htmlUpdate);
}
```

Is there a way I can do this in one line of code in JQuery (because this kind of thing is repeat many times in my code)? Thanks broverflows!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly this problem you should write this code in an external function and call it each time when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Try use method:

condition ? true : false

```
$editingElem.parent(".form-submit").length ? $editingElem.parent().before(response.d.htmlUpdate) : $editingElem.before(response.d.htmlUpdate);
```

Comment: I try to avoid using condition but if there is no answer in JQuery I will use that

Answer (score 0):

If you have to call code more than on time, it´s the best to put this code in a function, that you can call multiple times. 
If you have to make any changes in the future, you just have to edit in you function an every call will be affected by this changes.

### Functions

To declare a function in javascript, write this:

```
function exampleFunction() {
   // insert your code here
}
```

To call this function, you just type this:

```
exampleFunction();
```

If you need any variables to be given to your function, your could use function parameters:

```
function exampleFunction(parameterA, parameterB) {
   // insert your code here
   console.log(parameterA + parameterB);
}

exampleFunction(1, 4); // would log 5 to your console
```

### The solution for your problem

```
 function(selector, response) {
     if (selector.parent(".form-submit").length == 1) {
         selector.parent().before(response);
     }else {
         selector.before(response);
     }
 };
```

njow you can insert this function-call at everywhere you need it:

```
insertResponse($editingElem, response.d.htmlUpdate);
```